# with RVM, can multiple rails sites using different rvm's with nginx and passenger?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

with RVM, can multiple rails sites using different rvm's with nginx and passenger?

Answer (score 3):

Passenger 3 has support for this. You need to set up reverse proxying, pick which will be your default ruby, and use Passenger Standalone on a different port for each non-default version of ruby you want to use.

Have a read of [this article](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) on the Phusion blog - it explains it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

See [Installing RVM System Wide](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/) and [Deployment Best Practices](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/best-practices/).